# setting up django celery error running instance

Tags: django

I'm learning how to setup django-celery and I'm getting this error

```
[tasks]
  . revamp.celery.debug_task

[2017-08-20 05:58:06,216: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2017-08-20 05:58:08,230: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...

[2017-08-20 05:58:12,245: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds...

[2017-08-20 05:58:18,263: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 8.00 seconds...

[2017-08-20 05:58:26,283: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 10.00 seconds...

[2017-08-20 05:58:36,312: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 12.00 seconds...
```

here's their docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

when I run this command is when the error above appears

```
celery -A revamp worker -l info
```

my django project is called revamp and in revamp/revamp/celery.py here's the code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'revamp.settings')
app = Celery('revamp')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: i think you're misssing this part `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your celery app cannot find the message broker. Please install rabbitmq-server(sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server) and start(sudo service rabbitmq-server start) it. If already installed  restarting it will solve the issue.